# Selecting Pandas rows where more than 1 column is not NaN

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe set up in the following way:

```
header_1 | header_2 | header_3 | header_4

a            b         NaN        NaN
b            c          9          10
x            y         NaN         8
```

How can I select using column indexes (the name of the columns change) the rows where header_3 and header_4 are BOTH not NaN? header_3 and header_4 are integers

Thank you

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If possible multiple columns defined in list check not missing values of filtered columns with [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) for check all `True`s per rows:

```
cols = ['header_3','header_4']

df = df[df[cols].notnull().all(axis=1)]
print (df)
  header_1 header_2  header_3  header_4
1        b        c       9.0      10.0
# df[df[['header_3', 'header_4']].notnull().all(axis=1)]  # Just to avoid creating a list of cols and calling that.
```

For select by last 2 columns use [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) for select by positions:

```
df = df[df.iloc[:, -2:].notnull().all(axis=1)]
```

Also is possible specify columns by indexers:

```
#python count from 0
df = df[df.iloc[:, [2,3]].notnull().all(axis=1)]
# df[df.loc[:, ['header_3', 'header_4']].notnull().all(axis=1)]  # or can use loc with direct columns name
```

---

Or if only 2 columns chain conditions with `&` for bitwise `AND`:

```
df = df[df['header_3'].notnull() & df['header_4'].notnull()]
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer! Would there be a way to use column indexes instead? The two columns in questions are always the last in the dataframe but their names may change

Comment: @Macterror - Sure, check edited answer.

Comment: This did it! I will accept your answers in 6 minutes. Thank you so much

Comment: @jezrael, we can also add `df[df.loc[:, ['header_3', 'header_4']].notnull().all(axis=1)]` just for demonstration mentioning column names.

Comment: @pygo - yes, it is first solution `df = df[df[cols].notnull().all(axis=1)]`

Comment: but  there we are creating a list of columns whereas  in this case we don't need that and we are just define the desired columns in one go So, one line will be kind of one liner :-) just thought.   Any way +1

Comment: @pygo - yes,so think like `df = df[df[['header_3', 'header_4']].notnull().all(axis=1)]`  ?

Comment: @jezrael, yes or like using loc as `df[df.loc[:, ['header_3', 'header_4']].notnull().all(axis=1)]`

Comment: @jezrael, i just placed these two more lines in a shadow mode by commenting if you like you can accept :-)

Answer (score 3):

Also with `.dropna`

```
subset = ['header_3', 'header_4']
df.dropna(subset=subset, thresh=len(subset))

#  header_1 header_2  header_3  header_4
#1        b        c       9.0      10.0
```